# C# - Cannot retrieve an entity from DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I'm unable to retrieve an entity from the database with Entity Framework. I have an entity called *Order*. In order to retrieve the records, I do:

```
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrder(int id) {
    return Context.Orders.Where(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

As I'm working with the ViewModel pattern, I need to convert the *Order* entity to *OrderDTO*, so I do that conversion like this:

```
return orderManager.GetOrder(id).ToList().AsQueryable().ProjectTo<OrderDTO>().ToList();
```

The problem, is that when I do this conversion, I receive an error saying:

> 'The '*PaymentMethod*' property on '*Order*' could not be set to a
>   'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of type '*PaymentMethod*'.

Debugging, I have discovered that this happens when I do the *ToList()*. For instance:

```
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrder(int id) {
    var test = Context.Orders.Where(e => e.Id == id).ToList(); // fatal error

    return Context.Orders.Where(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Googling about this error, [this](https://www.trycatchfail.com/2015/01/26/entity-framework-enums-and-tinyint/) is the only related information I have found, but I'm not sure if I have to do the change explained in that blog. I have also tried this but it didn't work:

```
return Context.Orders.Include(e => e.)... //Nothing appears in Intellisense
//or
return Context.Orders.Include("PaymentMethod")...
```

**My code**:

*PaymentMethod* is an Enum like this:

```
public enum PaymentMethod
{
    PayPal,
    CreditCard,
    Transfer
}
```

*Order* entity is basically like this (it's larger but nevermind):

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public PaymentMethod PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how is the Order table defined? what are its columns and column types?

Answer (score 2):

```cs
return orderManager.GetOrder(id).ToList().AsQueryable().ProjectTo<OrderDTO>().ToList();
```

Here, the call ToList function prevents projection.
That's right:

```
return orderManager.GetOrder(id).ProjectTo<OrderDTO>().ToList();
```

And enumerations are treated in EF as numbers (int), not as strings.